# Creating a custom UIDatePicker with UITableViews with looping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

Currently I'm creating a project that requires the user to enter a date and time into the app as they're interacting with it, but I was not happy with how the standard UIKit `UIDatePicker` looked, so attempted to build my own.

Currently I have the functionality working fine with multiple `UITableView`s holding the day, hour, minute and optionally AM/PM if the user has specified non 24h time.

The bit I am stuck on is getting the tableViews to loop through the options as you get in a regular `UIDatePicker`. Is there any technique I could use to create this effect with a `UITableView`?

I've also briefly looked into `UIPickerView`s but am unsure whether the functionality of looping would be easier/harder with those than a tableView. I know the design of those can be customised with

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

As an example, the latest update for Clear has a custom date picker implementation:
[image: Clear Date Picker]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard way of doing this. Maybe you can check the tableview's scrollView content offset and adjust it to jump where you want it.

For it to work correctly so you can't see the jump you'll need to duplicate the number of cells.

Not sure if it's the best way, but this code works, try it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return numberOfCells*2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell N: %d", indexPath.row%numberOfCells];

    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if((scrollView.contentOffset.y+scrollView.frame.size.height)>=scrollView.contentSize.height) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height/2-scrollView.frame.size.height);
    }

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y<=0) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height/2);
    }
}
```